# Wreq or Servant for http API client?

Tags: haskell

I've been working in two different projects to implement a client binding for the Pivotal Tracker tool. [One project](https://github.com/diogob/pivotal-tracker-api) uses the [wreq library](https://github.com/bos/wreq), while [the other](https://github.com/utdemir/hs-pivotal-tracker) relies on [servant](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant).

I want to merge both projects, but I'm unsure of which design approach to use. So the questions that would help me to sort this out are:

1. Is there any concrete advantage of defining my API as a type (besides the readability)?
2. Which error handling will generate less code for users of the library, servant's `EitherT ServantError IO ()` or wreq's Exception style?

Comment: wreq has a few outstanding issues wrt supporting latest http-client and stackage nightly as of today.  servant is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 5):

Both use `http-client` under the hood.

In Haskell, the most consuming part of writing the web api bindings, are data definitions and JSON serialisation specification. The `wreq` implementation uses lenses, `wreq` is lensy HTTP library.

After that, you'd like to provide some functions (using `IO`) to fetch data from right endpoints:

```
getStory :: Options -> Int -> Int -> IO Story
getStory options projectId storyId =
    getOne options $ "/projects/" ++ show projectId ++ "/stories/" ++ show storyId
```

or

```
type API = "services" :> "v5" :> "stories"
             :> Header "X-TrackerToken" Text
             :> Capture ":storyId" StoryId
             :> Get '[JSON] Story

story :: Text -> StoryId -> EitherT ServantErr IO Story
story :<|> ... =  client api ...
```

They aren't that different. With `wreq` (or `http-client` directly) you'd probably implement some helper function (like `getOne`) to do fetches; when with `servant` you get it "for free".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'll have to rephrase my question since stack overflown does not bode well with opinion based questions.